# Making NGINX point to another container in ECS

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have built two images and pushed to ECR (Elastic Container Registry) , One is Nginx and another is API server.

Nginx image built using following dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

API image built using following dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine AS gowebserver
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go mod init main
RUN go mod tidy
RUN go build -o main  .
CMD ["/app/main"]
EXPOSE 9999
```

My nginx is as follows

```
upstream goweb {
    server gowebserver:9999;
}

server {
    listen 80;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://goweb;
    }

}
```

This works fine in local environment with docker-compose ,, but how do i make this work in ECS ? I have task definition with these two images I pushed to ECR. I have created two services ngnix and api ..

When I open IP of EC2 created via Cluster.

```
myipaddress:80 // nginx default page is loading
myipaddress:9999 // my api server page is loading
```

how do I make nginx container proxy pass to my another container service which is running at port 9999

I tried below , still it was not working.

```
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
```

Comment: Are you deploying the ECS tasks to EC2, or Fargate?

Comment: I am deploying to EC2

Comment: Which network mode have you selected? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html It would also be helpful to include your JSON task definition in your question.

Comment: I used bridge mode.

Comment: You need to link the containers via the `links` parameter in the ECS task definition: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html